# Rails: "BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash" when trying to sign in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, bcrypt

I am trying to finish a project. I am working with user models. 
When I signup everything seems ok . But when I try to signin the same member I get this error.

We're sorry, but something went wrong.
*heroku logs* file shows error as:

```
BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash (invalid hash):
  app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:8:in `create'
```

my ***sessions_controller*** is :

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

   def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end


  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

and **user model** is :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name, :nickname,:password, :password_confirmation 
  has_secure_password


  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
  before_save { |user| user.nickname = nickname.downcase }
  before_save :create_remember_token
....validations......

    private

    def create_remember_token
      self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end
end
```

this is my **session.helper**

```
module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    self.current_user = user
  end
  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
  end

  def sign_out
    self.current_user = nil
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end
end
```

I tried heroku rake db:migrate, heroku restart.. there is no change.

Comment: can you show us your `sign_in` method?

Comment: Edited my first message with session.helper in the message.there is the sign_in method

Comment: Just in case, have you done `bundle install` with `gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'` in your `Gemfile`?

Comment: yes bcrypty-ruby and and for production " pg "gem.

Comment: @ytsejam, Did you recently switch to using "has_secure_password" and were using a different authentication scheme before, and have an existing user database?

Comment: Can you try this? In sessions_helper.rb, for `sign_in` method, put `current_user = user` instead of `self.current_user = user`. BTW, does this work in Dev environment?

Comment: Ben lee , yes i changed the has_secure_password. before i used the wrong code with attr-accessor :password , :password_combination

Comment: @ytsejam, I don't really understand. What I'm asking is did you switch from using SHA1 or something like that, to BCrypt?

Comment: no i did not change. but i made a mistake in this line attr_accessible :email, :name, :nickname,:password, :password_confirmation 
  has_secure_password ( before i was trying attr_accessor) in this line

Comment: garbage collection .. it tells me invalid hash and the error is in this line     if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])

Comment: @JasonKim I am seeing the same error and have `bundle install` with `gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

This means that the hash stored in `password_digest` is not a valid BCrypt hash (including if the field is empty).

Based on the comments, it looks like you just created the user at a time the `has_secure_password` wasn't there, so the password digest never got stored. Look in the database, you'll probably see that `password_digest` is empty for that user. Remove the user from the database and re-create with your new working code and it should work.

While discussing with in the comments though, I made an (incorrect) guess about why the passwords would be wrong, and I already wrote up the explanation. So here it is for any future visitor that does have this problem, even though it doesn't apply directly here:

---

This typically happens when you switch from using SHA1 or another algorithm to BCrypt but fail to re-hash the passwords in BCrypt. Since you don't have access to the original passwords (or at least you shouldn't...), it's a bit ugly to switch because you have to use *both* BCrypt and the original authentication scheme. For example, if you were using SHA1 before and now use BCrypt, you have to treat the SHA1 password hash *as* the plain text password for BCrypt input. For example, you might create a BCrypt digest like this:

```
sha1_password = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("#{salt}#{real_password}")
self.password_digest = BCrypt::Password.create(sha1_password).to_s
```

Then, you can create bcrypt password_digests based on the sha1 password hashes that you *do* have access to.

You would authenticate like this:

```
sha1_password = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("#{salt}#{attempted_password}")
BCrypt::Password.new(self.password_digest) == sha1_password
```

I used SHA1 in the above examples, but this will work for other hashing algorithms as well.

Comment: I am using Devise and trying to migrate my database from Wordpress 4 ( i think it uses phpass). I get the invalid hash. Where do I write this BCrypt Digest so it can authenticate the passwords hashed from Wordpress?

Answer (score 24):

An update to the BCrypt gem fixed this issue for me

Comment: In my case, it seemed to be specific to the system. Since the same thing with the old version worked on another machine. So I updated the version of gem and worked for me.

Comment: This solved my problem too when I cloned https://github.com/gorails-screencasts/two-factor-authentication

Comment: In my case I went from bcrypt 3.1.11 to 3.1.16 and it resolved the error. https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/issues/4861 seems related. My previous password didn't work, I had to reset it.

Comment: Same here upgrading from 3.1.11 to 3.1.16 fixed it for me.

Answer (score 14):

I already had live users, and likewise already saved unencrypted passwords into the database. Once I started using bcrypt, it was expecting an encrypted password, and when it didn't find it, it produced this error.

Therefore, I added this rescue to catch the error and prompt the legacy users to reset their password:

```
begin
    # your code that attempts to login the user
rescue BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash
  flash[:error] = 'We recently adjusted the way our passwords are stored. Please click the "forgot username or password?" link to re-establish your password. Thank you for your understanding!'
  redirect_to password_resets_url
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to rely on authenticate() raising an undocumented exception; it's cleaner to work around it by checking password_digest.empty? before calling authenticate().

Comment: I also have existing users (though a small set).  I manually updated passwords with `u = User.find(...); u.password = "<the new password>"; u.save!` and sent everyone the new passwords.  The point here i guess is that simply updating the password via the model, sets everything up properly.

Answer (score 1):

"You just need to use 'password' instead of 'password_digest' when creating a user in your Rails application. For example:

Correct Input:

```
user = User.create(username: 'afaq', password: '1234')
```

Incorrect Input (avoid this):

```
user = User.create(username: 'afaq', password_digest: '1234')
```

Using 'password' ensures that the user's password is securely hashed and stored in the 'password_digest' field in your database. This is the recommended way to handle user passwords in Rails applications."