# Why is my password_digest returning an "invalid hash" error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing, bcrypt

I'm a bit confused about an error I'm getting from running an integration test for users to sign in.  Here are the first few lines of the trace:

```
invalid hash
    @ /home/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/lib/bcrypt.rb:171:in `initialize'
      /home/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activemodel-3.2.6/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb:58:in `new'
      /home/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activemodel-3.2.6/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb:58:in `authenticate'
      /home/benjamin/projects/LTClone/app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:9:in `create'
```

So the error is coming from this line in the `create` action:

```
if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
```

which calls the `authenticate` method defined in `secure_password.rb`:

```
def authenticate(unencrypted_password)
  if BCrypt::Password.new(password_digest) == unencrypted_password
    ...
```

which calls the `BCrypt::Password.new` method, which is defined in `bcrypt.rb`:

```
def initialize(raw_hash)
  if valid_hash?(raw_hash)
    ...
  else
    raise Errors::InvalidHash.new("invalid hash")        # line 171
  end
end
```

So for some reason, `raw_hash` is not matching the regex specified by `valid_hash?`, which means that the `password_digest` variable isn't a valid hash.  Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11038412/1543283), it would seem like the user I'm trying to authenticate has a blank or invalid `password_digest`, but before I call the `create` action in the test, I can `puts @user.password_digest`, and the hash is printed (and Rubular says the `valid_hash?` regex matches it).  I also changed the create method to

```
if user && user.password_digest && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
```

just to make sure it really really exists.

So now I'm just completely stumped.  It seems like I have a valid `password_digest`, but `BCrypt::Password.new` refuses to recognize it as such.  Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 2):

Check your User "password_digest" column. If it's "nil" then you will get this error. Suggestion is to simply delete all users and ensure users are properly created.

Comment: How do we delete all users?

Comment: You can delete all users from your console like
`MODEL.delete_all`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will be the same solution for you, but my issue (very same error) was resolved by changing the password in the fixture stored in the `test/fixtures/users.yml` file.  Once I saved and ran `rails test` again, the test passed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do an if/else to see if password or password_digest is nil

```
if user.password.nil?
  #redirect back to login with message
else

if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
  #do your stuff!
end
```