# Devise not authenticating users after upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

My rails app fails to authenticate users. It was initially on devise 1.4 and i upgraded the app to rails 4 and the latest devise gem. after taking the app to production and loading the initial users their accounts fails to sign in. i am getting the following error

```
A BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash occurred in sessions#create:
```

How can i make my users that registered with devise 1.4 sign in with the latest devise. There are over 1000 existing users unable to sign in to the app. only new users can sign in.
Any help thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is an old hashing algorithm. Please take a look at this answer:

["BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash" when trying to sign in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037864/bcrypterrorsinvalidhash-when-trying-to-sign-in)

Comment: How do i do this for devise gem