# "BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash" when joining a User Group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, passwords, bcrypt

I recently added has_secure_password to the User Group model for an app I'm building. I use a form to allow a user to join a group, and if they pass a valid group name and password, it should allow them to join. However, it looks as though the password (password_digest column in User Group table) isn't being encrypted, since I can see the password text when I run the authenticate command in rails console, and this seems to be what is throwing this error.

User Group Model:

```
class UserGroup < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :user_group_items
has_many :users
has_many :items, through: :user_group_items

has_secure_password
validates :password, :presence => true

validates :group_name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
```

Form:

```
<div class="container">
<h3>Join a group</h3>
<br>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <%= simple_form_for @group, :url => "/user_groups/", :method => :put do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>
    <div class="form-inputs">
        <%= f.input :group_name, :maxlength => 15 %>
        <%= f.input :password, :maxlength => 15 %>
        <br>
        <div class="form-actions">
            <%= f.button :submit, :class => "btn btn-primary", :value => "Join Group" %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Controller Method:

```
def update
    group_name = params[:id] || params[:user_group][:group_name]
    @user_group = UserGroup.find_by_group_name(group_name)
    if @user_group && @user_group.authenticate(params[:user_group][:password])
        current_user.update(:user_group => @user_group)
        redirect_to '/user_groups', :notice => "You have joined #{@user_group.group_name}"
    else
        redirect_to '/user_groups', :notice => "Error, couldn't join #{group_name}. Invalid group name or password"
    end
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't do it, it just causes a different error: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass.

Comment: Please post your  `development.log`  did it get the password you entered or get it from `params`

Comment: Processing by UserGroupsController#update as HTML
08:44:01 web.1  |   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"rfVoEu193Y128DmoODaLqiy8qXQ9RXsc3udf2++Sz7s=", "user_group"=>{"group_name"=>"Team lol", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Join Group"}
08:44:01 web.1  |   UserGroup Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "user_groups".* FROM "user_groups"  WHERE "user_groups"."group_name" = 'Team lol' LIMIT 1
08:44:01 web.1  | Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms
08:44:01 web.1  | BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash (invalid hash):
08:44:01 web.1  |   app/controllers/user_groups_controller.rb:23:in `update'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037864/bcrypterrorsinvalidhash-when-trying-to-sign-in

Comment: Check your User "password_digest" column. If it's "nil" then you will get this error

Comment: Thanks for the link, I reviewed it before posting my question. I didn't switch from another authentication scheme, and had no users/user groups before adding has_secure_password.

Comment: password_digest is not nil. From Rails Console:  UserGroup.find_by_group_name("Mighty Ducks").password_digest

 SELECT  "user_groups".* FROM "user_groups"  WHERE "user_groups"."group_name" = 'Mighty Ducks' LIMIT 1
 => "a"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem: I had the bcrypt gem installed, but didn't have bcrypt-ruby installed.