# Rails invalid hash password authenticates in ruby console but after reopening it doesn't. Why?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, authentication

I am following [lynda.com's Ruby on Rails 5 Essential Training][1] and am very stuck when building the login system.

The issue is the database seems to be holding a different hash to what rails is using. I have looked all over for reasons and fixes and I understand that the stored hash and the one rails runs are different but why and how can I fix this?

I have added:

> bcrypt 3.1.11 gem installed 
>  password_digest column in table 
>   has_secure_password to correct model file

I have migrated down and back up again to see if there are issues with the table.

The password stored in the database is **hashed - password_digest: $2a$10$AMHXZBl/zXQ9yHOR7uBSiOdsGloArDkxO**

I have even followed these steps in the Ruby console:

```
user.password = 'password'
user.password_confirmation = 'password'
user.save
user.authenticate('password')
```

The password saves and the authentication brings up the correct entry but it does not match after rerunning the console or using the login page on rails server.

I get this error each time:

```
BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash (invalid hash):

app/controllers/cms_access_controller.rb:16:in `attempt_login'
```

and invalid hash error in the browser gets stuck here:

```
found_user = CmsUser.where(:username => params[:username]).first
  if found_user
    authorized_user = found_user.authenticate(params[:password])
  end
end
```

Here is the log from rails:

```
Started POST "/cms_access/attempt_login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-01-02 17:59:18 +0800
Processing by CmsAccessController#attempt_login as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"YP2tiHyRfDhJhhuF+PPM0D+hA+6BMJW5YmTyZyLpT6nXs4NdhGyihVKZpoMaRl0oUsobnr6x5bYGBR75+huUjg==", "username"=>"username", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Login"}
[1m[36mCmsUser Load (0.4ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  `cms_users`.* FROM `cms_users` WHERE `cms_users`.`username` = 'username' ORDER BY `cms_users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1[0m
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 9ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)



BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash (invalid hash):

app/controllers/cms_access_controller.rb:16:in `attempt_login'
```

Full irb code as follows:

```
irb(main):001:0> u = CmsUser.first
   (0.4ms)  SET NAMES utf8,  @@SESSION.sql_mode = CONCAT(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@@sql_mode, 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES', ''), 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES', ''), 'TRADITIONAL', ''), ',NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'),  @@SESSION.sql_auto_is_null = 0, @@SESSION.wait_timeout = 2147483
  CmsUser Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `cms_users`.* FROM `cms_users` ORDER BY `cms_users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
=> #<CmsUser id: 1, first_name: "first name", last_name: "last name", email: "email", username: "username", password_digest: nil, created_at: "2018-01-02 14:48:42", updated_at: "2018-01-02 14:48:42">
irb(main):002:0> u.password = "password"
=> "password"
irb(main):003:0> u.password_confirmation = "password"
=> "password"
irb(main):004:0> u.save
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE `cms_users` SET `password_digest` = '$2a$10$gKAyDPTNzg.7Xnd7uatzuu0VWZNH6zGPA653RZ.5THB2Rziax1fyC', `updated_at` = '2018-01-02 14:50:29' WHERE `cms_users`.`id` = 1
   (1.1ms)  COMMIT
=> true
irb(main):005:0> u.authenticate("password")
=> #<CmsUser id: 1, first_name: "first name", last_name: "last name", email: "email", username: "username", password_digest: "$2a$10$gKAyDPTNzg.7Xnd7uatzuu0VWZNH6zGPA653RZ.5THB...", created_at: "2018-01-02 14:48:42", updated_at: "2018-01-02 14:50:29">
```

After running rails server and attempting login:

```
Started POST "/cms_access/attempt_login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-01-02 22:52:01 +0800
Processing by CmsAccessController#attempt_login as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"qF/U+46QhGZHYuEbfPTStRxryPpp0hIEt1TQIRVE5bgfEfoudm1a21x9XB2eQUNNcQDQilZTYgvTNTy/zbY+nw==", "username"=>"username", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Login"}
  CmsUser Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `cms_users`.* FROM `cms_users` WHERE `cms_users`.`username` = 'username' ORDER BY `cms_users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 11ms (ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)



BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash (invalid hash):

app/controllers/cms_access_controller.rb:16:in `attempt_login'
```

Comment: use debugger and check `params` and what does it output as hash?

Comment: How do I go about this please?

Comment: Please check the rails sever log and add request parameters to your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash" when trying to sign in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037864/bcrypterrorsinvalidhash-when-trying-to-sign-in)

Comment: No, I've seen this answer and I've tried making new entries while has_secure_password is present in the model file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to following sign in action like below

```
found_user = CmsUser.find_by(:username => params[:session][:username].downcase)
if found_user && found_user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
  #=> code to be here
else
  #=> code to be here
end
```

Hope to help