# Michael Hartl Ruby on Rails Tutorial Chapter 9 Failing Tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I tried looking for an answer to this question, but to no avail.

I'm getting this error message when I run rails test.

```
    1) Error:
UsersLoginTest#test_login_with_valid_information_followed_by_logout:
ActionView::Template::Error: invalid hash
    app/models/user.rb:32:in `new'
    app/models/user.rb:32:in `authenticated?'
    app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:21:in `current_user'
    app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:30:in `logged_in?'
    app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb__454288832_69555624'
    app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___219463369_68483868'
    test/integration/users_login_test.rb:45:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'

24 runs, 66 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

Here are the relevant files, any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks!

from user.rb

```
  # Returns the hash digest of the given string.
  def User.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                  BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end

  # Returns a random token.
  def User.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  # Remembers a user in the database for use in persistent sessions.
  def remember
    self.remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
  end

  # Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
  def authenticated?(remember_token)
    BCrypt::Password.new(remember_digest).is_password?(remember_token)
  end

  # Forgets a user
  def forget
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
  end
```

from sessions_helper.rb

```
  def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
      user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
      if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in user
        @current_user = user
      end
    end
  end

  # Returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise.
  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end
```

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersLoginTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
  end

  test "login with invalid information" do
    get login_path
    assert_template 'sessions/new'
    post login_path, params: { session: { email: "", password: ""} }
    assert_template 'sessions/new'
    assert_not flash.empty?
    get root_path
    assert flash.empty?
  end

  test "login with valid information" do
    get login_path
    post login_path, params: { session: { email:    @user.email,
                                          password: 'password' } }
    assert_redirected_to @user
    follow_redirect!
    assert_template 'users/show'
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user)
  end

  test "login with valid information followed by logout" do
    get login_path
    post login_path, params: { session: { email:    @user.email,
                                          password: 'password' } }
    assert is_logged_in?
    assert_redirected_to @user
    follow_redirect!
    assert_template 'users/show'
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user)
    delete logout_path
    assert_not is_logged_in? 
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    follow_redirect!
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path,      count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user), count: 0
  end
end
```

Edit: I won't allow any me to post anymore code, so if there's anything you'd need to see, let me know!

Comment: Did you read any of the [69 search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Michael+hartl+chapter+9) for the exact same chapter of the exact same book before you posted your question? It would be great if you included in your post what things you have tried from those duplicative questions and answers so anyone answering your question doesn't give you an answer you have already tried and failed to get working. I don't see anything at all in your post about what you've done to solve this on your own.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash" when trying to sign in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037864/bcrypterrorsinvalidhash-when-trying-to-sign-in)

Answer (score 0):

["BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash" when trying to sign in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037864/bcrypterrorsinvalidhash-when-trying-to-sign-in) Looks like the same issue you're encountering:

> This means that the hash stored in password_digest is not a valid BCrypt hash (including if the field is empty).
>
> Based on the comments, it looks like you just created the user at a time the has_secure_password wasn't there, so the password digest never got stored. Look in the database, you'll probably see that password_digest is empty for that user. Remove the user from the database and re-create with your new working code and it should work.

Comment: I get the error message when I try to log out. When I check the console, I see that a password_digest value was generated, but I also see that remember_digest is nil.

Not sure if that is the issue at hand

Comment: Did  you create the user after including the has_secure_password? If so try another user, if the error only occurs with the first user, the problem is their password digest. Recreating that user should solve the issue

Comment: Sorry I just saw this is occurring in a spec - can you include the spec where you generate the user please? It's probably an issue there

Comment: Just added the test file

Comment: So I just took a look at chapter 9 of the tutorial (yeah it's a Friday afternoon at work)

Comment: "The second call to delete logout_path in Listing 9.14 should raise an error due to the missing current_user, leading to a red test suite:"

Comment: Is that the stage you're at? If so you're expected to encounter an error at that point

Comment: Ah duh! I just got there, I didn't read or continue further due to the bug - but low and behold it's there explaining why it happens. So hopefully after that section, it'll be fixed. 

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem while following the tutorial (tests were failing).

I had a noobie mistake in my `test/fixtures/users.yml` file.

```yaml
michael:
  name: Michael Example
  email: michael@example.com
  password_digest: <% User.digest('password') %>
```

It should've been `password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>` and now error is to be gone.