# BCrypt InvalidHash with Clearance password resets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bcrypt, clearance

I'm new to Rails, coming from a PHP + Python background. I'm setting up a development environment on my machine based on a production database dump.

I can't log in to my dev environment because every user sign in fails with a BCrypt InvalidHash error, no matter the user or password.

I checked the `users.encrypted_password` hash against my password on an online BCrypt website--it matches correctly.

I wrote a quick script to reset all the passwords to see if there's some weird configuration difference between my Fedora machine and the prod Heroku config:

```rb
User.find_each do |user|
  user.password = 'password'
  user.save
end
```

But that's *still* failing with the same InvalidHash error, stack trace below:

```
/home/eric/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11/lib/bcrypt/password.rb:60:in `initialize': invalid hash (BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash)
    from /home/eric/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11/lib/bcrypt/password.rb:46:in `new'
    from /home/eric/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11/lib/bcrypt/password.rb:46:in `create'
    from /home/eric/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/clearance-1.16.1/lib/clearance/password_strategies/bcrypt.rb:28:in `password='
    from /home/eric/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/clearance-1.16.1/lib/clearance/user.rb:111:in `password='
    from db/reset_passwords.rb:9:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

clearance.rb config:

```rb
Clearance.configure do |config|
  config.rotate_csrf_on_sign_in = true
  config.password_strategy = Clearance::PasswordStrategies::BCrypt
end
```

Model details:

```
> User.column_names
=> ["id", "first_name", "email", "encrypted_password", "confirmation_token", "remember_token"]
```

What am I doing wrong? It seems like my dev environment is missing some kind of config.

Comment: I see you’re using Rails. You may want to look into Rails’ `has_secure_password` feature for using BCrypt to securely store passwords / authenticate users. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Clearance is a Ruby Gem that duplicates `has_secure_password` to automatically handle password resets and the like. If I can't figure out why Clearance is broken, I'll have to rip it out and replace it with the basic Rails `has_secure_password`. But the fact it's working fine in the production environment is extremely confusing.

Comment: Admittedly, I’ve never heard of Clearance, though I have a lot of respect for Thoughtbot. I’ll have to look into this gem sometime.

Comment: Should you be setting the `password_confirmation` as well?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11038412/10068463 This answer may be of help to you!

Comment: I answered that in my initial question, actually: "I checked the users.encrypted_password hash against my password on an online BCrypt website--it matches correctly." It's stored in the `users` table correctly and can be copied into another BCrypt service where the password is correctly hashed and compared. Something's wrong with this configuration of Rails/Clearance/BCrypt, but I've run out of places to look!

Comment: if you create a new user, with a password that is "password" does the encrypted password match what you were expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone suggested my OS is at fault. I tried a simple `BCrypt::Password.create("password")`, which failed the same way. That led me to their GitHub...

https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/issues/170

So bcrypt-ruby broke on Fedora 28+. Version 3.1.12 was pushed to fix that. Our project was still using 3.1.11.

Lesson learned: Check the dependent dependencies!