# How to fix BCrypt authentication invalid hash at login erorr

Tags: authentication, activerecord, sinatra, bcrypt

I am building out a very basic sinatra/active record app. I am using bcrypt for my authentication.
I have everything set up properly (I think) all of my tables are migrating, seed file/data base are working and yet Im getting an error when trying to login.
Any help for a better way to write my authentication is appreciated! Overall the steps of getting it set up seem straight forward, install bcrypt gem(which I have updated), table has a password_digest column and has_secure_password is present in my controller.
Here is my error along with code. any help appreciated!

Error

`BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash at /login invalid hash`

a backtrace given of this line from my users controller

`if user && user.authenticate(params[:user][:password])`

users controller

```
    get "/signup" do
        erb :"users/new"
    end 

    post "/signup" do
        user = User.new(params[:user])
        if user.save
            session[:user_id] = user.id 
            redirect "/users/#{user.id}"
        else 
            @errors = user.errors.full_messages.join(" - ")
            erb :'/users/new'
        end
    end

    get "/login" do
        erb :"users/login"
    end 

    post "/login" do
        user = User.find_by(username: params[:user][:username])
        if user && user.authenticate(params[:user][:password])
            session[:user_id] = user.id 
            redirect "/users/#{user.id}"
        else 
            redirect "/login"
        end
    end

    get "/users/:id" do
        @user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
        erb :"/users/show"
    end 

    get "/logout" do
        session.clear
        redirect '/'
    end 
end
```

user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_secure_password

 validates :username, presence: true
 validates :username, uniqueness: true

 has_many :tattoos
end
```

user table

```
def change
     create_table :users do |t|
    t.string :username
    t.string :password_digest
    t.timestamps null: false
  end
end
end
```

schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2022_02_11_170950) do
  create_table "tattoos", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "client"
    t.string "placement"
    t.string "description"
    t.integer "user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "username"
    t.string "password_digest"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end
end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate. Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11038412/117430) solve your issue?

Comment: I did have an error of duplicates in my gemfile. i deleted my gemfile.lock re-checked my gemfile and installed again as well as made sure my bcrypt was updated to the latest version. is there another way I could check if its  an issue of a duplicate?

Comment: or do you mean duplicate of a user? I do some some dummy seed data but I have also replanted that and checked that I currently only have one user created.